# Images aligning vertically instead of horizontally in IE?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have a problem with some images in IE, they are aligning vertically instead of horizontally, however they are fine in all other browsers? Also when using IE8 and 7 the images are not being displayed at all! Is there a way I can get around this? I have attached my code below:

```
<div class="header_right_christmas">
            <div class="preflang_christmas">
                    <a href="#" class="delivery_xmas">
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook_xmas">
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter_xmas">
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="pintrest_xmas">
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="google_xmas">
                    </a>
</div>
```

```
.preflang_christmas {float:right; display:inline-flex;}

.delivery_xmas {
height:40px;
width:196px;
display:block;
background-image:url('myimage.png')no-repeat;
}

.delivery_xmas:hover {
background-image:url('myimage.png');
}

.facebook_xmas {
width:40px;
height:40px;
display:block;
background:transparent url('myimage.png')no-repeat;
}

.facebook_xmas:hover {
background-image:url('myimage.png');
}

.twitter_xmas {
height:40px;
width:40px;
display:block;
background:transparent url('myimage.png')no-repeat;
}

.twitter_xmas:hover {
background-image:url('Christmas_Homepage_Images/twitter.png');
}

 .pintrest_xmas {
height:40px;
width:40px;
display:block;
background:transparent url('Christmas_Homepage_Images/pintrest_bw.png')no-repeat;
}

 .pintrest_xmas:hover {
background-image:url('Christmas_Homepage_Images/pintrest.png');
}

 .google_xmas {
height:40px;
width:40px;
display:block;
background:transparent url('Christmas_Homepage_Images/google_plus_bw.png')no-repeat;
}

.google_xmas:hover {
background-image:url('Christmas_Homepage_Images/google_plus.png');
}
```

Comment: what happens if you change your `block`s to `inline-block` in your css?

Comment: IE7-9 Don't support any type of flexbox layout. 10 Has a partial support.

Comment: in u'r css for image use: vertical-align: middle;

Comment: Is there any workaround for IE7-9?

Comment: @Adsy Adding inline-block fixes it for me in IE9+10 but I am still getting no images being displayed in IE7+8

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty good stuff. Have you made sure all your file location are correct and that they are case correct too?

Comment: @Adsy Yep everything seems fine! Its all working ok in all other browsers

Comment: Try using a JPEG instead of a PNG and see if that's the problem

Comment: @Adsy I managed to fix it I don't really know how/why this worked but I just removed the `no-repeat` from the background-image and it now displays! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix by removing `no-repeat` off of background-image!